# Reading XML element from different Descendants

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

In the XML, the third element named "DocumentIdentification" is also the file name of the XML. How would I add that number to every row in the code below when the array reads out the three items to the datagridview. I am a little lost on the implementation part. Some XML documents do have the "DocumentIdentification" in the "FilingLeadDocument" but some don't. Any ideas that might be useful while still applying only the code below because it is functioning as designed.

C# Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var documentsData = GetDocumentsData(@"\\DIS2\EFilingXML\Test");
    var receivedFilesDataTable = new DataTable("ReceivedFiles");

    receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Received On", typeof(DateTime)));
    receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
    receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Register Action", typeof(string)));

    foreach (var dataPiece in documentsData)
    {
        var row = receivedFilesDataTable.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = dataPiece;
        receivedFilesDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = receivedFilesDataTable;
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"\\DIS2        \EFilingXML\Test")
{
    var filingMessageNamespace = XNamespace.Get("urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0");
    var ncNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
    var ecfNamespace = XNamespace.Get("urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0");
    var jNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0");

    return Directory
      .GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
      .Select(XDocument.Load)
      .SelectMany(file => file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingLeadDocument").Concat(file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingConnectedDocument")))
      .Select(documentNode =>
                    new object[]
                    {
                        //documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentIdentification").Element(ncNamespace + "IdentificationID").Value.Trim(),
                        DateTime.Parse(documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentReceivedDate").Element(ncNamespace + "DateTime").Value),
                        documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentDescriptionText").Value.Trim(),
                        documentNode.Element(ecfNamespace + "DocumentMetadata").Element(jNamespace + "RegisterActionDescriptionText").Value.Trim(),
                    }).ToArray();
}
```

XML Format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<RecordFilingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServiceMessagingProfile-Definitions-4.0">
  <RecordFilingRequestMessage xmlns:fsrsp="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:FilingStatusResponseMessage-4.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:j="http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:juvenile="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:JuvenileCase-4.0" xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" xmlns:domestic="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:DomesticCase-4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:criminal="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CriminalCase-4.0" xmlns:amcadext="http://www.amcad.com/NiemEcf/extensions/1.0" xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0" xmlns:appellate="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:AppellateCase-4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:citation="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CitationCase-4.0" xmlns:reviewcb="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0" xmlns:civil="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CivilCase-4.0">
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueueId">476</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueue">Circuit Criminal Existing Cases</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:IdentificationID>6379325</nc:IdentificationID>
    </nc:DocumentIdentification>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:56:14.290623-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="REVIEWER">
        <nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonGivenName></nc:PersonGivenName>
          <nc:PersonSurName></nc:PersonSurName>
          <nc:PersonFullName></nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>27404</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID></nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
          <nc:ContactInformation>
            <nc:ContactEmailID></nc:ContactEmailID>
          </nc:ContactInformation>
        </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
      </ecf:EntityPerson>
    </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
    <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <nc:IdentificationID>Filing Review MDE</nc:IdentificationID>
    </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
    <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
    <CoreFilingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0">
      <nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
      <nc:DocumentIdentification>
        <nc:IdentificationID>6379325</nc:IdentificationID>
      </nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
      <nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
        <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="FILER">
          <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName></nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonSurName></nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonNameSuffixText s:metadata="III">III</nc:PersonNameSuffixText>
            <nc:PersonFullName></nc:PersonFullName>
          </nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>24759</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>STB</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>128820FL</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>BAR_NUMBER</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID></nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>EMPLOYER</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
            <nc:ContactInformation>
              <nc:ContactEmailID></nc:ContactEmailID>
              <nc:ContactMailingAddress>
                <nc:StructuredAddress>
                  <nc:AddressDeliveryPointText></nc:AddressDeliveryPointText>
                  <nc:LocationCityName></nc:LocationCityName>
                  <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>FL</nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                  <nc:LocationStateName></nc:LocationStateName>
                  <nc:LocationPostalCode></nc:LocationPostalCode>
                </nc:StructuredAddress>
                <nc:AddressFullText></nc:AddressFullText>
              </nc:ContactMailingAddress>
              <nc:ContactTelephoneNumber s:id="PRIMARYPHONE">
                <nc:FullTelephoneNumber>
                  <nc:TelephoneNumberFullID></nc:TelephoneNumberFullID>
                </nc:FullTelephoneNumber>
              </nc:ContactTelephoneNumber>
            </nc:ContactInformation>
          </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
        </ecf:EntityPerson>
      </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:SendingMDELocationID s:id="Filing Assembly MDE">
        <nc:IdentificationID>http://www.myflcourtaccess.com/Courts/UIPages/SimpleEFileFees.aspx?organizationId=5</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>209.16.117.2</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
      <ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation s:id="1">
        <ecf:ServiceRecipientID s:id="24759" s:metadata="Samuel Bookhardt III">
          <nc:IdentificationID>;</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>Electronic</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </ecf:ServiceRecipientID>
      </ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation>
      <ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation s:id="2">
        <ecf:ServiceRecipientID s:id="-1" s:metadata="Phil Archer, State Attorney">
          <nc:IdentificationID>;;</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>Electronic</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </ecf:ServiceRecipientID>
      </ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation>
      <criminal:Case>
        <nc:ActivityDescriptionText s:id="Circuit Criminal">Other Crimes Against Persons</nc:ActivityDescriptionText>
        <nc:ActivityStatus>
          <nc:StatusText>ORIGINAL PEND                           </nc:StatusText>
          <nc:StatusDate>
            <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T00:00:00-04:00</nc:DateTime>
          </nc:StatusDate>
        </nc:ActivityStatus>
        <nc:CaseTitleText></nc:CaseTitleText>
        <nc:CaseCategoryText s:id="40781916530">904</nc:CaseCategoryText>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID></nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID s:id="ucn"></nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <j:CaseAugmentation>
          <j:CaseCourt>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>5</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>2</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION_UNIT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Trial</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>COURT_TYPE</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Eighteenth Circuit</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>JUDICIAL_CIRCUIT_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationName></nc:OrganizationName>
            <nc:OrganizationUnitName>Circuit </nc:OrganizationUnitName>
            <j:CourtName></j:CourtName>
          </j:CaseCourt>
        </j:CaseAugmentation>
        <ecf:CaseAugmentation>
          <nc:LanguageCode xsi:nil="true" />
        </ecf:CaseAugmentation>
      </criminal:Case>
      <FilingConfidentialityIndicator>false</FilingConfidentialityIndicator>
      <FilingLeadDocument s:id="DOC00001" s:metadata="# Pages=3">
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Motions">Motion to Set Bond</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">101</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067143">3022      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:FilingPartyID>
            <nc:IdentificationID>24759</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </ecf:FilingPartyID>
          <ecf:SpecialHandlingInstructions />
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
            <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
            <nc:DocumentFileControlID>bond jeremey carmichael.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
            <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00001">
              <nc:BinaryBase64Object></nc:BinaryBase64Object>
              <nc:BinarySizeValue>12862</nc:BinarySizeValue>
              <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>1</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
            </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
          </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </FilingLeadDocument>
      <FilingConnectedDocument s:id="DOC00002" s:metadata="# Pages=1">
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Notices">Notice of Hearing</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">102</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>2</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067191">6724      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:FilingPartyID>
            <nc:IdentificationID>24759</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </ecf:FilingPartyID>
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
            <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
            <nc:DocumentFileControlID>NOH Bond Nebbia 10.11.13.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
            <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00002">
              <nc:BinaryBase64Object></nc:BinaryBase64Object>
              <nc:BinarySizeValue>8812</nc:BinarySizeValue>
              <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>2</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
            </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
          </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </FilingConnectedDocument>
    </CoreFilingMessage>
    <RecordDocketingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:RecordDocketingMessage-4.0">
      <nc:DocumentIdentification>
        <nc:IdentificationID>6379325</nc:IdentificationID>
      </nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:56:14.290623-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
        <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="REVIEWER">
          <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName></nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonSurName></nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonFullName></nc:PersonFullName>
          </nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>27404</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID></nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
            <nc:ContactInformation>
              <nc:ContactEmailID></nc:ContactEmailID>
            </nc:ContactInformation>
          </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
        </ecf:EntityPerson>
      </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>Filing Review MDE</nc:IdentificationID>
      </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
      <j:CaseCourt>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>5</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>2</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION_UNIT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>Trial</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>COURT_TYPE</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>Eighteenth Circuit</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>JUDICIAL_CIRCUIT_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationName>Brevard</nc:OrganizationName>
        <nc:OrganizationUnitName>Circuit Criminal</nc:OrganizationUnitName>
        <j:CourtName>Brevard Circuit Criminal</j:CourtName>
      </j:CaseCourt>
      <nc:CaseTrackingID>052013CF050219AXXXXX</nc:CaseTrackingID>
      <ecf:ReviewedLeadDocument s:id="REVIEWEDDOC00001">
        <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <nc:DocumentStatus>
          <nc:StatusText>ACCEPTED</nc:StatusText>
        </nc:DocumentStatus>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067143">3022      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:ParentDocumentReference s:ref="DOC00001" />
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata s:metadata="3" />
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </ecf:ReviewedLeadDocument>
      <ecf:ReviewedConnectedDocument s:id="REVIEWEDDOC00002">
        <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>2</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <nc:DocumentStatus>
          <nc:StatusText>ACCEPTED</nc:StatusText>
        </nc:DocumentStatus>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067191">6724      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:ParentDocumentReference s:ref="DOC00002" />
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata s:metadata="1" />
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </ecf:ReviewedConnectedDocument>
    </RecordDocketingMessage>
    <payment:PaymentMessage xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-1.0" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-1.0" xmlns:receipt="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:PaymentReceiptMessage-4.0" xmlns:payment="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:PaymentMessage-4.0">
      <payment:PayerName></payment:PayerName>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="NA" identificationSchemeName="Filing fee" identificationSchemeAgencyID="-1">NA</cac:ID>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:PrepaidIndicator>false</cbc:PrepaidIndicator>
        <cbc:SequenceNumeric>1</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
        <cbc:Amount amountCurrencyID="USD">0</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:Reason>Filing fee</cac:Reason>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="NA" identificationSchemeName="Motions Motion to Set Bond" identificationSchemeAgencyID="101">NA</cac:ID>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:PrepaidIndicator>false</cbc:PrepaidIndicator>
        <cbc:SequenceNumeric>2</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
        <cbc:Amount amountCurrencyID="USD">0</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:Reason>Motions Motion to Set Bond</cac:Reason>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="NA" identificationSchemeName="Notices Notice of Hearing" identificationSchemeAgencyID="102">NA</cac:ID>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:PrepaidIndicator>false</cbc:PrepaidIndicator>
        <cbc:SequenceNumeric>3</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
        <cbc:Amount amountCurrencyID="USD">0</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:Reason>Notices Notice of Hearing</cac:Reason>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:Address>
        <cac:AddressLine>
          <cbc:Line>1980 Michigan Ave.</cbc:Line>
          <cbc:Line />
          <cbc:Line>Cocoa</cbc:Line>
          <cbc:Line>FL</cbc:Line>
          <cbc:Line>32922</cbc:Line>
        </cac:AddressLine>
      </cac:Address>
    </payment:PaymentMessage>
  </RecordFilingRequestMessage>
</RecordFilingRequest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Parent` property for getting the `DocumentIdentification` at the top of the xml document.

```
(string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentIdentification")
```

Then your code will look like this:

```
return Directory
         .GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
         .Select(XDocument.Load)
         .SelectMany(file => file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingLeadDocument").Concat(file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingConnectedDocument")))
         .Select(documentNode =>
                 new object[]
                 {
                    (string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentIdentification"),
                    DateTime.Parse(documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentReceivedDate").Element(ncNamespace + "DateTime").Value),
                    documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentDescriptionText").Value.Trim(),
                    documentNode.Element(ecfNamespace + "DocumentMetadata").Element(jNamespace + "RegisterActionDescriptionText").Value.Trim(),
                    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you. I would like to learn more, indepth, about this subject of XML as it is becoming a more common task for me. Any ideas?

Comment: There are many tutoriasl no the web for Linq to Xml, for instance check this on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx and lots of samples for almost everything at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=C%23&f%5B0%5D.Text=C%23&f%5B1%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B1%5D.Value=LINQ&f%5B2%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B2%5D.Value=LINQ%20to%20XML

Comment: how do I account for .Concat(file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingConnectedDocument"))) when the XML returns only the file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingLeadDocument")? This will be the case for the XML that has only one image with the information available.

Comment: Are you having an issue? If there is no FillingConnectedDocuments the concat should work anyway. Maybe I am not understanding your problem

Comment: I am getting a Null Exception error but everything is in the XML.

Comment: Try to split you query into several parts to identify where it is failing.

Comment: Found my issue. If you looked at the variable named ncNamedSpace, I have multiple "var ncNamespace = XNamespace.Get("niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");"; to account for. the error getting hit is "xmlns:s="niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0";. How do I account for the multiple ones because every XML is different.

Comment: I suggest you to  put another question with this issue explained it in detail. I am not sure I fully undestand the problem.